# CompiledQuery throws ArgumentException

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, compiled-query

I'm trying to use a very simple pre-compiled query within an extension method to retrieve data using LINQ to SQL.  SytelineRepository is my custom DataContext that uses external mapping files, and I'm querying the JobOrders table.  I've been using the custom DataContext for a long time without issue and executing the same query with no problem; I'm just trying to improve performance.  However when I try to use CompiledQuery.Compile I get the ArgumentException below.

Here's the code:

```
public static class Queries
{
    public static readonly Func<SytelineRepository, String, IQueryable<JobOrder>> GetOpenJobOrdersForItemQuery =
        CompiledQuery.Compile(
        (SytelineRepository r, String itemNumber) => 
            from job in r.JobOrders
            where job.ItemNumber == itemNumber
            select job
        );

    public static IQueryable<JobOrder> GetOpenJobOrdersForItem(this SytelineRepository r, System.String itemNumber)
    {
        return GetOpenJobOrdersForItemQuery(r, itemNumber);
    }

}
```

As a contrast, this works:

```
    public static IEnumerable<JobOrder> GetOpenJobOrdersForItem(this SytelineRepository r, System.String itemNumber)
    {
        return GetOpenJobOrdersForItemUncompiledQuery(r, itemNumber);
    }

    public static IQueryable<JobOrder> GetOpenJobOrdersForItemUncompiledQuery(SytelineRepository r, String itemNumber)
    {
        return
            from job in r.JobOrders
            where job.ItemNumber == itemNumber
            select job;
    }
```

Here's the full error:

> System.ArgumentException was unhandled
>
> Message=Property 'System.String ItemNumber' is not defined for type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Mpicorp.SytelineDataModel.JobOrder]'

```
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Property(Expression expression, PropertyInfo property)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlBinder.Visitor.AccessMember(SqlMember m, SqlExpression expo)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlBinder.Visitor.VisitExpression(SqlExpression expr)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlBinder.Visitor.VisitBinaryOperator(SqlBinary bo)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlBinder.Visitor.VisitExpression(SqlExpression expr)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlBinder.Visitor.VisitSelect(SqlSelect select)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlBinder.Visitor.VisitIncludeScope(SqlIncludeScope scope)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlBinder.Bind(SqlNode node)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.BuildQuery(ResultShape resultShape, Type resultType, SqlNode node, ReadOnlyCollection`1 parentParameters, SqlNodeAnnotations annotations)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.BuildQuery(Expression query, SqlNodeAnnotations annotations)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Compile(Expression query)
   at System.Data.Linq.CompiledQuery.ExecuteQuery(DataContext context, Object[] args)
   at System.Data.Linq.CompiledQuery.Invoke[TArg0,TArg1,TResult](TArg0 arg0, TArg1 arg1)
   at Mpicorp.SytelineDataModel.Queries.GetOpenJobOrdersForItem(SytelineRepository r, String itemNumber) in C:\SVN\Mpicorp.SytelineDataModel\trunk\SytelineDataModel\Queries.cs:line 21
   at Mpicorp.SytelineDataModel.SytelineRepository.GetTimePhasedInventory(String itemNumber, Boolean includeForecast) in C:\SVN\Mpicorp.SytelineDataModel\trunk\SytelineDataModel\SytelineRepository.cs:line 242
   at RepriceWorkbench.TimePhasedInventoryForm..ctor(SytelineRepository repository, String itemNumber) in C:\SVN\spirepriceutility\trunk\src\POWorkbench\TimePhasedInventoryForm.cs:line 32
   at RepriceWorkbench.TimePhasedMenuForm.goBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\SVN\spirepriceutility\trunk\src\POWorkbench\TimePhasedMenuForm.cs:line 25
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at RepriceWorkbench.Program.Main() in C:\SVN\spirepriceutility\trunk\src\POWorkbench\Program.cs:line 66
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: I take it the exact same query works when not compiled? There are no differences (other than the code necessary to make it a compiled query)?

Comment: Yes, the exact same code works when not compiled, and has been in production for over a year.

Comment: What happens if you call it from non extension method?

Comment: Can you post the full stack-trace and the inner exceptions if there is any?

Comment: The same problem.  Originally this function was defined within the DataContext itself, but that was throwing the same error so I moved it to an extension method so it would be closer to the example I was referencing.

Comment: Can you post the definition of job.ItemNumber?

Comment: I found the problem.  It was in the SytelineRepository definition.  Posting the answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment from usr led me to review the definition underlying the code I posted, and that's where I stumbled across the long-forgotten fact that my table stores several different objects and I was differentiating between them using the repository's accessors, like this:

```
    public IQueryable<JobOrder> JobOrders
    {
        get { return GetTable<JobOrder>().Where(j => j.JobType == 'J'); }
    }
```

Changing the method to use GetTable<>(), as in the following fixed the issue.

```
    public static readonly Func<SytelineRepository, String, IEnumerable<JobOrder>> GetOpenJobOrdersForItemQuery =
        CompiledQuery.Compile(
        (SytelineRepository r, String itemNumber) =>
            from job in r.GetTable<JobOrder>()
            where job.ItemNumber == itemNumber && job.JobType == 'J' && (job.Status == "F" || job.Status == "R")
            select job
        );
```